# Make marker message/label clickable in angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using angular-leaflet-directive and am trying to make my marker messages clickable.  When I use html in the marker message the html is rendered correctly but ng-click doesn't work.  Here's what I have.

```
 $scope.map.markers.push({
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    message: '<span ng-click="openView()">' + data.results[i].locationName + '</span>',
    draggable: false
});
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong or know how to call a function when the marker message is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

You can now easily use Angular templates in a popup message:

```
$scope.openView = function() { ... };

$scope.map.markers.push({
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    message: '<span ng-click="openView()">' + data.results[i].locationName + '</span>',
    getMessageScope: function() {return $scope; }
});
```

Comment: @WootWoot Yes, since versions 0.7.10. Still in development.

Answer (score 0):

You are in big trouble :P. The only way to make new angular code work out of the box is by using the $compile service. I don't mean to be rude, but if i were in your place, i'd try to find another approach like using an ng-repeat and changing your logic.

Anyway, the compile service works somewhat like this but at least personally i'd try to find a different solution:

```
angular.module('sampleApp', [])
  .directive('howCompileWorks', ['$compile', function($compile){
    return {
      template: '',
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attr) {
        scope.shout = function(){
          alert("I SAID HELLO!!");
        }
        element.html('<span ng-click="shout()">Hello yo!</span>');

        $compile(element.contents())(scope);
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree, I don't want a messy solution.  I'm just looking for a way to make the label of markers clickable.  I'm not sure what you mean about using ng-repeatbut I'm interested.  Do you mind explaining how I can use it to make the marker label clickable?  Thanks.

Comment: I was thinking something like js without html:
$scope.map.markers.push({
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng,
    message: data.results[i].locationName,
    draggable: false
});

Comment: THIS ONE IS THE COMMENT: I was thinking something like this but i don't know if it can apply to your project.
At js change this line:: message: data.results[i].locationName
At your view add this:: <span ng-repeat="marker in map.markers" ng-click="openView()">{{marker.message}}</span>